# CommandInteraction suddenly stopped working / Discord.js slashcommands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This code was working perfectly up until now:

```
const {Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed, Permissions} = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name : 'ban',
    description : "bans the target member",
    options: [
        {
            name: "target",
            type: "USER",
            description: "select a target",
            required: true,
        },

        {
            name: "reason",
            type: "STRING",
            description: "specify a reason",
            required: false
        },
    ],
    /**
    * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
    * @param {Client} client
    * @param {Permissions} permission
    */
    async execute(client, interaction, permission) {
        const Target = interaction.options.getMember('target')
    }
}
```

Now it says that `interaction.options.getMember` is not a function, literally 5 minutes ago it was. Please help me I cannot find any typo. It just does not make sense.

This is the command handler, provided that all of the commands are already uploaded to the server (since I have checked that there is nothing wrong with that part), the following code takes care of creating and handling said commands:

```
const {Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",

    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */

    async execute(interaction, client, arguments) {
        if(interaction.isCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if(!command) return interaction.followUp({content: "This command no longer exists."}) && client.commands.delete(interaction.commandName);
            
            const arguments = [];

            for(let option of interaction.options.data) {
                if(option.type === "SUB_COMMAND") {
                    option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                        if(x.value) arguments.push(option.value);
                    });
                } else if (option.value) arguments.push(option.value);
            }

            command.execute(interaction, client, arguments);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Log interaction and confirm it's an interaction object, then confirm the properties you are trying to access exist

Comment: It’s possible you are passing in client in the interaction argument spot (client has options property - [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=options))

Comment: @MrMythical vscode clearly shows that is is an  interaction, but nodejs suddenly does not care

Comment: Where are you logging it? How are your arguments passed in?

Comment: @MrMythical I have a command handler that takes those modules and turn them into slash commands

Comment: Can you maybe edit it in?

Comment: @MrMythical those are 2 kinda big files but I will sum it up

Comment: You executed it with `interaction, client, arguments` but it should be `client, interaction, arguments` (I posted an answer)

Comment: Also, I don’t understand the last argument. In your command file you said it was Permissions but in the command handler it said it was an array of options

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that `interaction` is not an interaction object. I suspect it is actually a `Client` object. It could be anything with an `options` property though. Make sure the arguments passed in the file you execute this with are ordered correctly like this:

```js
someVar.execute(client, interaction, arguments)
//someVar is what you use to require this file
//client is an instance of Client
//interaction is an instance of CommandInteraction
//I don’t know the class of arguments
```

Comment: it just says the same thing over and over, I am on the verge of giving up

Comment: Well what does it say?

Comment: interaction.options.getMember is not a function

Comment: How did you try to pass in the arguments now? In execution

Comment: client, interaction, arguments , it just does not make sense, it stopped working out of the blue

Comment: could be you upgraded from v13 to v14, there's breaking changes all over with discordJS in this area

Comment: @dcsan no that doesn't make sense, v14 was only released last week